# How to pass entity object to controller from custom validation annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I've a request `data transfer object`(DTO) which is for accepting POST body of an API. That DTO has an ENUM key of an `X` entity. I created a custom validation annotation and validate that ENUM exists in my system via its entity repository which returns entity or null based on its existence.

I want to pass that `X` validated entity to my controller. I don't want to fetch that `X` entity by ENUM again in my business logic because I've already done that in validation.

I save that entity in a static variable from annotation validator class and access it later when I want that in business logic but if API get hit concurrently, my static variable gets overridden by the second request and when my business logic of the first request fetches `X` entity, it gets the entity of the second request due to override issue.

I want that `X` entity object to be scoped inside its own request cycle and destroyed or GC after request completion like other objects. How can I achieve this?

My Custom Validator:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidateXimpl.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidateX {
    String message()  default "Message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}
```

Custom validator implementation:

```
public class ValidateXimpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateX, String> {

    @Autowired
    DBRepo dbRepo;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidateX annotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        try {
            XEntity X = dbRepo.findByEnum(value); // I want this entity in my controller
            return (!value.isEmpty() && X != null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My DTO where I put my validation:

```
public class DTO{
    ....
    @ValidateX
    String xEntityEnum
    ....
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/x', method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> createX(@Validated @RequestBody DTO dto, BindingResult errors) {
    // I want that entity here which I get from db repo in my validator
}
```

Comment: If you use a form object to receive your request parameters with, you can validate the fields in that object and it will be passed to the controller method.

Comment: this is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010820/3959856

Comment: No, I created an other object in my custom validator and I want that object to be passed in controller.

Comment: hmm ok. one way could be to just validate the indata and then create the new object in the get-method for that field in the dto. would that work?  btw, some code would help

Comment: Your bullet list makes your question unreadable. Please rephrase your question. Don't use bullet list unless you are really listing items. For a question, use normal prose.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I edit my question. Thank for pointing that out. I'll take care from onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this from `RequestContextHolder`

Solution Code:

**Validator Implementation**

```
public class ValidateXimpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateX, String> {

@Autowired
DBRepo dbRepo;

@Override
public void initialize(ValidateX annotation) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
    try {
        XEntity X = dbRepo.findByEnum(value); // I want this entity in my controller
        RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().setAttribute(
                "XEntity", X, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST
        ); // I saved it in RequestContextHolder
        return (!value.isEmpty() && X != null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
}
```

**My Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/x', method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> createX(@Validated @RequestBody DTO dto, BindingResult errors) {
     // I want that entity here which I get from db repo in my validator
    System.out.println(
            RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute(
                    "XEntity",
                    RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST
            )
    ); // I get that from RequestContextHolder
}
```

This is what I actually need. `RequestContextHolder` gets clear on request completion and also only available in its own request thread because of request scope setting in `setAttribute` function.